# How to transform a dataframe to have values of a column as new columns, grouped by other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Excel file as below

[Excel Raw File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuUJw.png)

I want to plot the output by groupby Name and Fruit on the left hand side and top groupby date as shown as below.

[Outcome Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0JWN.png)

I tried create the Excel file like this:

```
Output = dt.groupby(['Name','Fruits'])['QTY'].sum()
```

but I do not know how does the QTY can split by the Date on top of it.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Im using spyder

Comment: Spyder is an IDE for Data Science. You're most likely using the pandas python module for dealing with tabular data (DataFrames)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If your indexes are duplicated, use `pivot_table()` instead and use an aggregation function like this (see the note at the end of [this section](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects)):

```py
df.pivot_table(index=['Name', 'Fruits'], columns=['Date'], values='QTY', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
```

That gives me the following results:
[image]

**ORIGINAL**

If using Pandas, you can pivot the DataFrame as such:

```py
df.pivot(index=['Name', 'Fruits'], columns=['Date'], values='QTY').fillna(0)
```

The fillna() call places zeroes where the table has NaNs. If you don't mind that, you might as well just remove that function call.

Comment: i found error on this ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. That i think i need to sum up the qty ?

Comment: i believe it is because of my 'Name' and 'Fruits' are duplicated, but I can't remove the duplication as it will removed my data points as well

Comment: @RynxYee I've updated my question to provide a solution that does manage duplicate indexes IF aggregating by sum is ok for your use case

Comment: It is works!! thanks for the great help!!, which mean only pivot table can use the aggfunc as I tried

Comment: @RynxYee Yep. The link to the documentation says exactly that: use pivot_table when indexes are duplicated to use an aggregation function